# Spring Cloud Data Flow Log Level

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm using 2.7.0-RC1 Spring Cloud Data Flow on kubernetes. Although we pass an argument --logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.local=DEBUG to SCDF run command, I'm still viewing INFO level bug.

How can we change log level to DEBUG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.local` flag is to set the log level of the **local-deployer**. Your deployer is on Kubernetes.

From the Spring Cloud Dataflow docs in the section [Deployment Logs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/_logging.html#_deployment_logs), there are equivalent settings available for other deployers.
Refer this section:

> Similar to the local-deployer and cloudfoundry-deployer options as
> discussed above, there are equivalent settings available for Apache
> YARN, Apache Mesos and Kubernetes variants, too. Check out the
> respective SPI implementations to find out more details about the
> packages to configure for logging.

Since you are deploying on Kubernetes, if you want to view the deployment logs, try this flag (**note:** I have not tested this):

```
--logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.deployer.spi.kubernetes=DEBUG
```

Your question does not specify if you want to view the deployer logs, or the application/stream logs. If you want to view the streaming application logs refer this link on [Application Logs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/_logging.html#_application_logs).